# Do any laser keyboards allow you to move around keys to your liking?

Tags: keyboard, performance, typing, keyboard-layout

The lack of uniformity of the pgup print screen arrows etc is getting on my nerves.  I am wondering if any of the laser keyboards would make me a more efficient keyboarder by allowing me to adjust those keys and make fewer mistakes in programs, emails, and administrative tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are stating that you'd like to go from a physical keyboard to a laser keyboard to improve your typing skills. As well, the only laser keyboard I have experience with had an odd layout that completley lacked the "pgup print screen arrows etc" which you complained about being non-standard, as well as having keys squished into a trapezoid.

I believe you will find it impossible to touch type on a laser keyboard. Typing requires tactile feedback to know where your fingers are at all times.

A better solution to your problem is probably to pick a standard keyboard layout and use it everywhere you can.  Personally, I use upwards of four different keyboard daily, but they are all almost the same.  My pet peeve with keyboards is the location of the \ key which tends to move around.

I like to use vi-style keybindings, so I wouldn't miss the keys outside of the main "block" of keys on a standard 101 keyboard.

Comment: I would not to improve my skills but my keyboard experience.  I have been reading on ergonomics and the lack of tactile response.  I appreciate the feedback.  I have to wonder why laser keyboards would not have easy advantages over physical ones in terms of key placement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a laser keyboard is, but the [Ergodex DX1](http://www.ergodex.com/mainpage.htm) lets you move the keys around. Very useful for some things, but I doubt that typing would be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you're planning to use that a lot, if you don't have a "good touch/feeling" keyboard, you will have problems mostly with your hands... Ergonomacy is very important specially if your working lots of hours in front of your computer. Have you imagined what it is like introducing 5000 words in a day without having the smooth and pleasing feature of the keys suspension!? imagine typing 5000 words all day long knocking your fingertips all day long in a wooden table. That's got to hurt!